# React Native: Keyboard keeps closing on key press when typing in TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, textinput, usecallback

I have a functional component Login Screen and have 4 Input Fields in them, along with a login button.
Here is the Full Code for my component Screen:

```
export default function Login() {
  //Configs
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const orientation = useDeviceOrientation();
  const { colors, dark } = useTheme();

  const InputTheme = {
    colors: {
      placeholder: colors.accent,
      primary: colors.accent,
      error: "red",
    },
  };

  /** State Codes */
  //States
  const [login, setLogin] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
    licenseKey: "",
    deviceName: "",
  });
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [secureEntry, setSecureEntry] = useState(true);

  //Errors
  const [errorEmail, setEmailError] = useState(false);
  const [errorPWD, setPWDError] = useState(false);
  const [errorLicense, setLicenseError] = useState(false);
  const [errorDevice, setDeviceError] = useState(false);

  //Error Messages
  const [messageEmail, setEmailMessage] = useState("Looks Good");
  const [messagePWD, setPWDMessage] = useState("All Good");

  async function VerifyInputs() {
    var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*(\.[a-z0-9]+(\-[a-z0-9]+)*)*\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
    if (login.email == "") {
      //Email cannot be empty
      setEmailMessage("Email cannot be Blank!");
      setEmailError(true);
      return;
    } else if (login.email != "" && !pattern.test(login.email)) {
      //Email is not valid
      setEmailMessage("This is not a valid email address!");
      setEmailError(true);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("resolved email");
      setEmailMessage("");
      setEmailError(false);
    }
    if (login.password == "") {
      //Password cannot be empty
      setPWDMessage("Password cannot be Empty!");
      setPWDError(true);
      return;
    } else if (login.password.length < 5) {
      //Password must be minimum 5 characters.
      setPWDMessage("Password must be of minimum 5 characters!");
      setPWDError(true);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("resolved password");
      setPWDMessage("");
      setPWDError(false);
    }
    if (login.licenseKey == "") {
      //License Key can't be Empty
      setLicenseError(true);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("License resolved");
      setLicenseError(false);
    }
    if (login.deviceName == "") {
      //Device Name can't be empty as well
      setDeviceError(true);
      return;
    } else {
      console.log("Device name resolved");
      setDeviceError(false);
    }
    Toast.show("Validation Successful");
  }

  function MobileContent() {
    console.log("mobile_content rerendered");
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.accent }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}></View>
        <View style={{ flex: 3, justifyContent: "center" }}>
          {/**Main Content */}
          <View style={[styles.content, { backgroundColor: colors.primary }]}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              {/**For Header */}
              <Header />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 5 }}>
              {/**For Content */}
              <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <LoginContent />
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              {/**For Footer */}
              <Footer />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  function TabContent() {
    console.log("tab_content rerendered");
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: colors.accent,
          flexDirection: orientation.landscape ? "row" : "column",
        }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
          }}></View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1.5, justifyContent: "center" }}>
          {/**Main Content */}
          <View style={[styles.content, { backgroundColor: colors.primary }]}>
            {/**Header Wrapper */}
            <View style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
              {/**Header Title */}
              <Header />
            </View>
            {/**Content Wrapper */}
            <LoginContent />
            {/**Footer Wrapper */}
            <View style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
              {/** Login Button */}
              <Footer />
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  function Header() {
    console.log("header_component rerendered");
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: "5%" }}>
        <Title>Welcome User</Title>
        <Subheading>Please Sign In to Continue..</Subheading>
      </View>
    );
  }

  function Footer() {
    console.log("footer_component rerendered");
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: isTablet ? "5%" : "3.5%" }}>
        <Button
          title="Login"
          loading={false}
          ViewComponent={LinearGradient}
          containerStyle={{ maxWidth: isTablet ? "45%" : "100%" }}
          buttonStyle={{ height: 50, borderRadius: 10 }}
          linearGradientProps={{
            colors: [colors.accent, colors.accentLight],
            start: { x: 1, y: 1 },
            end: { x: 1, y: 0 },
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            VerifyInputs();
            //navigation.navigate("verify");
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  function LoginContent() {
    console.log("login_component rerendered");
    return (
      <View style={{ margin: "3%" }}>
        {/**Login & Email Wrapper */}
        <View style={{ flexDirection: isTablet ? "row" : "column" }}>
          <View style={styles.input}>
            <TextInput
              mode="outlined"
              label="Email"
              value={login.email}
              error={errorEmail}
              theme={InputTheme}
              onChangeText={(text) => setLogin({ ...login, email: text })}
            />
            {errorEmail ? (
              <HelperText visible={true} type="error" theme={{ colors: { error: "red" } }}>
                {messageEmail}
              </HelperText>
            ) : null}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "center" }}>
              <TextInput
                mode="outlined"
                label="Password"
                value={login.password}
                error={errorPWD}
                theme={InputTheme}
                secureTextEntry={secureEntry}
                style={{ flex: 1, marginBottom: 5, marginEnd: isTablet ? 15 : 5 }}
                onChangeText={(text) => setLogin({ ...login, password: text })}
              />
              <Button
                icon={
                  <Icon
                    name={secureEntry ? "eye-off-outline" : "eye-outline"}
                    size={30}
                    color={colors.primary}
                  />
                }
                buttonStyle={{
                  width: 55,
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  backgroundColor: colors.accent,
                  borderRadius: 10,
                }}
                containerStyle={{ marginStart: 5 }}
                onPress={async () => setSecureEntry(!secureEntry)}
              />
            </View>
            {errorPWD ? (
              <HelperText visible={true} type="error" theme={{ colors: { error: "red" } }}>
                {messagePWD}
              </HelperText>
            ) : null}
          </View>
        </View>
        {/**License & Device Wrapper */}
        <View style={{ flexDirection: isTablet ? "row" : "column" }}>
          <View style={styles.input}>
            <TextInput
              mode="outlined"
              label="License Key"
              value={login.licenseKey}
              error={errorLicense}
              theme={InputTheme}
              onChangeText={(text) => setLogin({ ...login, licenseKey: text })}
            />
            {errorLicense ? (
              <HelperText visible={true} type="error" theme={{ colors: { error: "red" } }}>
                License Key cannot be Empty!
              </HelperText>
            ) : null}
          </View>
          <View style={styles.input}>
            <TextInput
              mode="outlined"
              label="Device Name"
              value={login.deviceName}
              error={errorDevice}
              theme={InputTheme}
              onChangeText={(text) => setLogin({ ...login, deviceName: text })}
            />
            {errorDevice ? (
              <HelperText visible={true} type="error" theme={{ colors: { error: "red" } }}>
                Device Name cannot be empty
              </HelperText>
            ) : null}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={"dark-content"} backgroundColor={colors.accent} />
      {isTablet ? <TabContent /> : <MobileContent />}
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

As you can see by looking at the code.. my `Login` component's rendering responsive component layouts based on device type being phone or tablet, the following components `MobileContent` or `TabContent`.

`MobileContent` functional component wraps my main content in a ScrollView & `TabContent` functional component doesn't need a scrollview but has responsive scaling views.

Both of these parent components display my common components, `Header`,`LoginContent` & `Footer`.

My `Header` component just displays a standard title & subheading. My `LoginContent` component has all the TextInput fields in them with validation logic setup as well. My `Footer` component has the Submit/Login button. That's All.

So we can summarize the components tree for screen as:

Login Screen/Parent Component => Mobile Content/Tab Content => Header, LoginContent & Footer (Common Components)

Alright, so now what is the issue? the major issue for me lies for TextInputs in `LoginContent` component, but I assume the underlying issue is applicable for entire Login Screen component.

**The ISSUE:** When I click on TextInput fields, the input gets focus and Keyboard appears. Everything is fine till this point. As soon as I type even a single letter, single key press on keyboard.. *The Keyboard closes immediately and the text input is lost focus.*

Why it could be happening? I believe this might be the classic 'React Component Re-render' problem, which causes by TextInput to be re-rendered when state is updated by the `onChangeText` for the TextInput and hence it loses focus & that's why the Keyboard closes.

So, I hope to resolve atleast first issue from these two issues.

Issue 1: How do I prevent the Keyboard from constantly closing when I try to type something in any of the TextInput fields.

Issue 2: How can I better optimize my Parent & Children components rendering on every state update using the any of these two React Hooks `useCallback()` and `useMemo()`?

I've read the documentation for these two hooks `useCallback` & `useMemo` multiple times and still haven't grasped the concept of these hooks. All posted examples deal with a Counter Exmaple optimized using useCallback or useMemo but I'm not working with Counters here in my Screen.

I need a more practical exmaple of `useCallback()` & `useMemo()` in screen components. Perhaps an implementation of these two hooks in my current Login Screen component will help me understand & grasp the concept better.

Like I mentioned, solving Issue 1 is my highest priority atm, but I know a solution for Issue 2 will help me in the long run as well. It will be very helpful if you can resolve both of my issues here. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I found something, Please have look to this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60048240/12329984

Comment: @SumitSharma2 That is not a valid solution in my case. I've tried the answer from that question and the keyboard's still gets hidden on every key press