# Entering input causes modal reloading automatically

Tags: react-native, react-native-modal

In my React Native 0.62.3 app, a `modal` is used to collect user input. Here is the view code:

```
import { Modal, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
const [shippingCost, setShippingCost] = useState(0);
const ReturnModal = () => {
        if (isModalVisible) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                <Modal visible={isModalVisible} 
                            animationType = {"slide"}
                            transparent={false} 
                            onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
                        <View style={styles.modal}>
                            <Text>Enter Price</Text>
                            <TextInput keyboardType={'number-pad'} onChange={priceChange} value={price} autoFocus={true} placeholder={'Price'} />
                            <TextInput keyboardType={'number-pad'} onChange={shChange} value={shippingCost}  placeholder={'SnH'} />
                            <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
                            <Button title="Cancel" style={{bordered:true, backgroundColor:'red'}} onPress={modalCancel} />
                            
                            <Button title="OK" style={{bordered:true, backgroundColor:'white'}} onPress={modalOk} />
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                </View>
            )    
        } else {
            return (null);
        }
    }

    return (
            <Container style={styles.container}>
               //.....view code

              <ReturnModal />
      
          </Container>
    )
```

Here is 2 functions to reset state of `price` and `shippingCost`:

```
  const priceChange = (value) => {
    if (parseFloat(value)>0) {
        setPrice(Math.ceil(parseFloat(value)));
    }
};

const shChange = (value) => {
    if (parseFloat(value)>=0) {
        setShippingCost(Math.ceil(parseFloat(value)));
    }
};
```

The problem is that whenever entering in the price field with keystroke, the modal reloads/resets itself automatically. Tried `onChangeText` in `TextInput` and it has the same problem.

Comment: <TextInput keyboardType={'number-pad'} value={price} onChange={priceChange} autoFocus={true} placeholder={'Price'} />

Comment: with `onChangeText`, the automatical reloading of the modal after each and every key stroke still happened.

Comment: Is this also happening when you enter a keystroke inside the second text input, the one with shipping cost?

Comment: both price and shippingcost fields have the same problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891992/keyboard-dismisses-while-typing-textinput-in-nested-functional-component-react-n/60048240#60048240

Comment: your values refer to undefined state since it's defined outside component

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're declaring your hooks outside your component. Try putting them inside your ReturnModal function instead, like this:

```js
const ReturnModal = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(0);
  const [shippingCost, setShippingCost] = useState(0);
  ...
```

Documentation reference: [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Also, I would strongly recommend using the [React Hooks ESLint Plugin](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#eslint-plugin) (among others) to detect issues with your hooks. Here is a guide on how to add this to your React Native project: [Add Eslint Support to your React Native Project + React Hooks Rules](https://medium.com/swlh/add-eslint-support-to-your-react-native-project-with-react-hooks-1bbac3fac25d).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using animationType = {"slide"} try using animatonType : 'none'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).