# Keyboard closes after every keypress in TextInput react native

Tags: react-native, keypress, textinput

I am working on a react-native app in which I am facing a problem with the TextInput.

Whenever I press a key on the keyboard, the keyboard closes down.

I have tried using different text input components like material text input and 'react-native-elements' input. However the same issue exists.

*There are similar questions on stackexchange but they are all trying to fix this problem in TextInput. However, the problem is not in the TextInput but somewhere in the implementation of TextInput.*

I have simplified the code to:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const [additionalComments, setAdditionalComments] = useState("");

  const StarFeedback = () => {
        return (
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Additional Comments"
              onChangeText={text => setAdditionalComments(text)}
              value={additionalComments}
            />
        )
  }
  

  return (
    <View>
      <StarFeedback/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
});
```

Link to snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@rachitkohli/634602

Comment: Check this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891992/keyboard-dismisses-while-typing-textinput-in-nested-functional-component-react-n>

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, {useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

  const Aux = () => {
    const [additionalComments, setAdditionalComments] = useState("");

    const handleAdditionalCommentsChanged = (text) => {
      setAdditionalComments(text);
    };

        return (
          <View >
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Additional Comments"
              onChangeText={handleAdditionalCommentsChanged}
              value={additionalComments}
            />
          </View>
        )
  }
  

const App = () => {

  return (
    <View>
      <Aux/>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`Aux` component is declared inside `App` component and `additionalComments` is state of `App` component, so it is getting refreshed every time as the prop passed to it is changing.

Comment: "Yes, it helps me. When creating groups, variables should be defined within the same group."

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use the `value` attribute on each input. It's better (less re-renders) to use a `useRef`and make use the `onEndEditing` to store the value.

```js
import React, {useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    const [additionalComments, setAdditionalComments] = useState("");

    const inputEl = useRef(null);


    const handleInputSubmit = useCallback((ev) => {
        const input =  ev.nativeEvent.text;

    // validate all you want here

      setAdditionalComments(input)
    }, [setAdditionalComments]);

    const Aux = () => {
        return (
            <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
                <TextInput
                    ref={ inputEl }
                    placeholder="Additional Comments"
                    onEndEditing={ handleInputSubmit }
                    defaultValue={additionalComments}
                />
            </View>
        )
  }
  
...
```

This way the component will only be update **WHEN** the user finishes the input.

You could use the `onChange` to show a warning label for example (or for pre-fetching a search result, etc). But it's not worth to set a state on each key input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer João. Your answer is working however the user would have to submit every time he puts an input.
That's an additional step for the user.
However, I would like to use onChangeText to make the user proceed without using the submit button on the keyboard. But when I use onChangeText I face the same issue of keyboard getting closed.
Can you please tell me how can I fix it? 
Thanks!!

Comment: Just change the `onEndEditing` to a `onChangeText` on the TextInput component. As the name suggest: one run at the end and one runs everytime the user changes it's input. You can use the `handleInputSubmit` in my answer as a starting point